# How can I share VS Code keybindings between Windows and MacOS?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using Visual Studio Code on Windows for quite a while, and over time I have configured several personal keybindings. Now I am starting to use a Mac in addition to my Windows machine. When turning on settings sync, I realized that while all my settings and extensions are set up properly just like on my Windows instance, the keybindings are not. My keybindings JSON file is just empty.

I am using settings sync via my GitHub profile.

Is there a way to share my keybindings between Windows and Mac using settings sync? Or are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [sync setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_configuring-synced-data) to disable separate keybindings per platform:

```json
"settingsSync.keybindingsPerPlatform": false
```

This will make your settings synced between Windows and Mac. If you want to define a platform specific keybinding within this shared file, use the `isWindows` or `isMac` conditions:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+j",
    "command": "workbench.action.openSettingsJson",
    "when": "isWindows"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+j",
    "command": "workbench.action.openSettingsJson",
    "when": "isMac"
}
```